# Button onclick ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to put together a webpage that has multiply pages in 1 file which checks the session that i've created to show a page according to the session value. 
However, i want to create a button that does a ajax call on the background and returns the results thought JSON, BUT i don't know if i'm doing it the right way. 
I have this js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var alert = $('.Cmessage'); // DIV TO PUSH RESULTS TO

$("#terug").on('click', function(){

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.XXX.nl/shop/offerte/back.php', // form action url
  type: 'get', // form submit method get/post
  dataType: 'json', // request type html/json/xml 
  beforeSend: function() {
    alert.fadeOut();
  },
success: function(result) {
    if(result.error){
        alert.html(result.html).fadeIn();
        console.log(e)
    }else{
        alert.html(result.html).fadeIn();
        }
    }
});
});
});
```

This js needs to check whenever i click on:

```
<button type="button" class="terug">Open/Laden</button>
```

But somehow i fail to get it attached to the class "terug" and do something with it.

Does anybody has any suggestions/idea's on how i can do this better and get it working ? :P

Greetings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting your button with the wrong jQuery selector.

> $("#terug").click..

Try to use **$('.terug')** instead.

**'#' selecting by id

'.' selecting by class**

Answer (score 2):

You made a typo.

`#terug` is an **id selector**

`<button type="button" class="terug">` doesn't have an **id attribute**

Either use a class selector (`.`) or use an id attribute.

Comment: I'm very new to JS and everything i tried wasn't working so whatever you think you can report my question for would be very stupid in my opinion.

Comment: atleast everybody is posting something usefull so i can keep going on with my little project. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your selecting an id # when you should be using a class selector.

$(".terug").on('click', function()

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are doing it right. Now use jQuery append to add content to some html element (div usually) instead of alerting it.

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Sorry i wasn't finished with the question but i will checkout the link you posted.

Comment: I would say .. use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You are using class. But I used # to call the  class. You should  use .(dot) instead of #.